# Create HTML table row dynamically with c#

Tags: c#, html

I want to add a row in `HTML` table with `C#` method, I have written the code but after execution the row appears at the top of the page not under `HTML` table.

```html
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Plot No.</th>
    <th>Area</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Phase/Division</th>
    <th>Remarks</th>
    <th>Documents</th>
</tr>
```

```
public void AddRow() {
    string html = "<tr>" +
        "</td> <td class=\"text-right\"><a href = \"javascript:void(0)\"  ><i class=\"fa fa-pencil\" ></i></a>  </td>" +
        "<td><p>1</p></td>" +
        "<td><input type = \"date\" runat=\"server\" style=\"width:140px\" /></td>" +
        "<td><input type =\"text\" runat=\"serve\"' style=\"width:100px\" /></td><td>" +
        "<input type = \"text\" runat=\"server\" style=\"width:100px\"/></td>" +
        "<td><input type = \"text\" Value=\"Test2\" runat=\"server\"/></td>" +
        "<td><input type = \"text\" runat=\"server\" style=\"width:100px\"/></td>" +
        "<td><input type = \"text\" runat=\"server\" style=\"height:50px\"/></td><td>" +
        "<input type = \"file\" runat=\"server\" style=\"height:50px\"/></td></tr>";
    Response.Write(html);
}
```

and calling this function from `<a>` tag in the table.

```
<td>
    <a href="#" runat="server" onserverclick="Unnamed_ServerClick">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil" runat="server"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

and it appears on the top like this.[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7MWV.jpg)

Comment: Can you post the surrounding html? Are you sure you are not adding the row after the </table> tag?

Comment: Also, when are you calling this? When are you writing the rest of the page to the response? Is this part of an asp net app?

Comment: Unable to to add more code, but yes i am sure this all HTML is under table tag.

Comment: I don't have enough context to help you then.

Comment: Its an ASP .net application

Comment: Why are you doing this in c#? It's mostly HTML, it'd be better if you added it to aspx

Comment: For starters your AddRow() returns invalid html. You close a TD tag without opening it on the second line.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the TagBuilder:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs